# Ionic Datepicker and Timepicker

Tags: android, ionic-framework, datepicker

I am trying to build datepicker and timepicker components in my Ionic app for android.

I have looked for various libs and plugins, but I was not able to find what I wanted -- iOS style date and time picker which user can scroll to go through dates and times like image below.

[image]

Any advice and suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're looking for. Have you seen this, though
https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @Marko I was looking for WheelPicker answered below. And I have seen that lib. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [drumjs](https://github.com/3epnm/drumjs) javascript library.

You can easily create wheel with following code using this library.

```
<body class="outside">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        ...
        <option selected>39</option>
        ...
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
    <script>
       $("select").drum();
    </script>
 </body>
```

see the example of datepicker like ios [here](https://mb.aquarius.uberspace.de/drumjs/examples/datetime.html)

Comment: This works but has a little performance issue on android device.

Answer (score 1):

In Android it is called WheelPicker,I suggest you to use

[WheelPicker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker)

```
compile 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**OR**

You can use [CharacterPicker](https://github.com/ImKarl/CharacterPickerView)

```
CharacterPickerWindow mOptions = new CharacterPickerWindow(activity);

setPickerData(mOptions.getPickerView());

mOptions.setSelectOptions(0, 0, 0);

mOptions.setOnoptionsSelectListener(new OnOptionChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOptionChanged(int options1, int option2, int options3) {

    }
});
mOptions.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Could you show me any ionic or simple angularjs example?